# GitHub & Eclipse - Issue in cloning

Tags: eclipse, git, github

We have recently started using GitHub for saving our automation package and we were able to commit, push, pull, and other operations properly.

But recently we had to enable 2FA in Git, after which we couldn't perform any operation like commit/push/pull... so we tried to clone the project again and try perform these actions, but surprisingly we couldn't even clone the project now. Please help in understanding this - how can we clone the project and perform other regular actions of Git in Eclipse after enabling 2FA?

Comment: Have you followed these instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

Comment: Yeah, it worked... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used git with 2FA but I had come across this when I was looking into. hope they help

https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/

and this

https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/